# FileStream.Position Has Thread-Unsafe Side-Effects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Here is some code that writes 10 GB to disk while monitoring the progress of the write by periodically printing the write stream position on a background thread:

```cs
string path = "test.out";
long size = 10 * 1000L * 1000L * 1000L;
using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    // Get a handle (and don't do anything with it)
    var handle = writer.SafeFileHandle;

    // Start a background position reader
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(writer.Position);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    });

    // Write out the bits
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    long position = 0;
    while (position < size)
    {
        int count = (int)Math.Min(size - position, buffer.Length);
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        position += count;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you run this code, you will see that less than 10 GB get written. Basically, some random small fraction of the writes get forgotten and don’t get to disk.

This problem doesn’t occur very often. Of the 10 GB that this code tries to write, more than 99% get successfully written. If you read Position less often, the problem will occur even less often. We found this problem because we have some code that is supposed to monitor the throughput of machine-to-machine file copies (by reading Position every 30s on a background thread), and we detected a few hundred instances of file corruption in the billions of copies we make per day. But the basic scenario of monitoring stream progress from another thread seems likely to be extremely common, so this probably hits quite a few people, albeit at a very low rate.

The effect doesn't depend on whether one uses the old thread pool API or the new Task based API, whether one uses Write or WriteAsync, or how careful one is about Dispose/Close. It does depend on whether the file handle is exposed: if you comment out the line that reads the SafeFileHandle property, all 10 GB get written. Note that we don't actually do anything with the handle; simply having read it causes the misbehavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What’s going on here is that FileStream (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,e23a38af5d11ddd3) maintains a Boolean flag _exposedHandle that is true if it thinks that handle it uses internally has been exposed externally. If _exposedHandle is true, then when you read Position it runs a private method VerifyOSHandlePosition() which synch’s its own internal position value with that of the handle before returning it. Since that sync’ing code is not thread-safe, writes and reads happening at the same time can get screwed up.

Now FileStream doesn’t claim to be thread-safe. But that's a weak-sauce defense, because everyone expects that of course FileStream isn't safe for state-changing reads and writes, but still pure property reads are supposed to be side-effect-free and thus intrinsically thread-safe. List and Dictionary, for example, are not thread-safe, but reading their Count properties won't screw up reads and writes happening on another thread.

I can guess why the writers of FileStream added this. It allows you to hold an external handle, and do (synchronized) reads and writes using both the FileStream and the handle. But I think this wasn't the right way. If you hold an external resource that is also being used internally by another class (e.g. an array that is also used by a class or method that you have handed to it), then it's on you not to screw up. The class shouldn't try to compensate in a way that changes the way the class functions (and makes all operations take a performance hit as well), but instead should have made a public SynchronizeHandlePosition() method and told people who wanted this scenario to use it.

Since FileStream is what it is, keep in mind:

- Avoid FileStreams with exposed handles if at all possible.
- Know that Position for a FileStream with an exposed handle has thread-unsafe side-effects.
- Know that a FileStream with an exposed handle has reduced performance.

It would be nice if Microsoft updated the docs to say this stuff.